# Any way to dynamic update a binary (executable file) at running time without halt?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, assembly

Consider we have produced a program with `C++`, 1 year ago and it is working continuous and without any stop!

at the 1 year ago we don't know one day we should update it (due to fixing some bugs). so we didn't implement any [DSU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Software_Updating) (Dynamic Software Updating) instruction on it. also it doesn't run in virtual machine that let me too access its memory or context.

now how can do update (add or remove some functions, data types or instructions) in it without halt and stop it.

any recommendations?
thanks.

Comment: if you use plugins, you could probably unload and reload them in a controllable manner. If you use scripting, that should be even less problem. To update the application core, you'd want to have some kind of shell application, which is stable, but the application core is a plugin of the shell. Then you could update dynamically, perhaps.

Comment: yes, but the drawback of our software is the atomicity. it doesn't have core layer or shell ... . all of the code is compiled just in a .exe file that serves everything that we want to do.

Comment: It is possible to inspect/modify running process memory using Debugging Functions (ReadProcessMemory, WriteProcessMemory etc.). That method is really tricky and requires a deep knowledge of assembler and windows background. 
Program can not be stopped even for a time 100ms? Could you provide more information about why you can't do it?

Comment: What is the program doing? If it happens to be a network service, just install a parallel one, use DNS to redirect the clients there, wait until there are no clients on the prod instance, replace the prod instance and return DNS back. No interruption in service, unless it supports sessions/cookies of some kind.

Comment: it doesn't run on network. it is core of a controller for medical purposes

Answer (score 3):

You would have to attach a debugger to it. Stop it at an execution point where you won't destroy anything, replace the executable image, realign instruction pointers and if you chose a bad interrupt point you will also have to realign the stack and modify variables that may be affected/added by the new code.

It's a lot more hassle then you want to have.

If your modification is local then you may be better off with a code cave as a temporary solution to this particular running instance.

Comment: i voted up your answer but we cant stop it even a moment! this is very important to us. debuggers stop the program which we don't want to do it.

Comment: seems like a very interesting situation. Why haven't you thought an updating system?

Comment: You could create another program with debugger token privilege enabled to modify code, but this will cause problems with the cpu's cache which may contain the code being modified.

Comment: Any solution with debuggers we evaluated but it cause stop the program or crash! we are thinking about producing a system that get access to PE's context in memory and alter it concurrently.